# How to remove strings with word boundary which has special chars in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to remove sub string from a sentence using replaceAll api.

```
Ex: String str = "Condition (Where Clause) Address Line1 Collectable (%)"
    str = str.replaceAll("Condition \\(Where Clause\\)","");
```

This works fine, but if String is like `Condition (Where Clause)xyz` then also it is removing `Condition (Where Clause)` and resulting string will have `xyz`. I want to replace exact match only. For this I am trying with `\b` but it has special char `)` at the end. So, `\\bCondition \\(Where Clause\\)\\b` is not working.

```
Ex: String str = "Condition (Where Clause) Address Line1 Collectable (%)"
    str = str.replaceAll("\\bCondition \\(Where Clause\\)\\b","");
```

This is not working because of special character. 
How can I remove exact matching. I have to remove exact matching only which can have special characters also.

I tried with regex `Pattern` as well but same result.

Update:

I can not use `\s` because it can be at the end of the line also.
   I am thinking about to use like `Condition \\(Where Clause\\)(\b|\s|$)`. I am looking for any other better solutions.

Comment: if you want it to consider only whitespaces use `\s`

Comment: Could you give us some more input with the expected output? THe confusing part for me is that "Condition (Where Clause)" is not a word, but you are talking about exact words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible test cases based on your explanation:

```
"Condition (Where Clause) Address Line1 Collectable (%)"
"Condition (Where Clause)xyz"
"xyzCondition (Where Clause)"
"At the end: Condition (Where Clause)"
" Condition (Where Clause) "
"xyzCondition (Where Clause)xyz"
"In Condition (Where Clause) Between"
```

If you only want to remove `"Condition (Where Clause)"` exactly, except when it's directly followed by something other than a space or the end of the String, you could use this:

```
str.replaceAll("(^|\\s)Condition \\(Where Clause\\)(\\s|$)", "$1$2")
```

This will keep any leading or trailing spaces, so the last test case above becomes `"  "`.
If you also want to remove those leading spaces, so the last test case becomes an empty String `""`, you can remove the `$1$2` above.

This would result in (with the first line of each test case keeping the spaces, and the other removing them):

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##vZHBTsMwDIbvfQor6qREGpXGcZxGT0hw2oEDASlrPZaRpVXjbgzWKw/AI/IiJV07QYUq7USkxJH92f5lr9VWXazTl7pOjHIO7pS27wFAXi6MTsCRIm@2mU5h40N8ToW2zw@PoESDASyzonMCoaNYOYQpWNzBCW259rA4s6kmnVng9yssEGKjSocCZmlaoBdwqy1OIM6MwYTUwiDwkWDjc2q87t/6oHcMsX1wRkArBLTpFM7LGMTgbAl/5N7Y4arXSDtEyypxGmczbX4aubg6equguf75vbcj2K1I27ykrsR87wg3UVZSlPsgLTmTbOQkg6@PT2i/0rJxm9SZqMDcqARnxnDGnw5SOvEjWsqebCkF98Ah9MMDFk7CSyY6pf/dvGtcBVVdfwM) to see it in action.

```
"Condition (Where Clause) Address Line1 Collectable (%)" → " Address Line1 Collectable (%)"
"Condition (Where Clause) Address Line1 Collectable (%)" → "Address Line1 Collectable (%)"
"Condition (Where Clause)xyz" → "Condition (Where Clause)xyz"
"Condition (Where Clause)xyz" → "Condition (Where Clause)xyz"
"xyzCondition (Where Clause)" → "xyzCondition (Where Clause)"
"xyzCondition (Where Clause)" → "xyzCondition (Where Clause)"
"At the end: Condition (Where Clause)" → "At the end: "
"At the end: Condition (Where Clause)" → "At the end:"
" Condition (Where Clause) " → "  "
" Condition (Where Clause) " → ""
"xyzCondition (Where Clause)xyz" → "xyzCondition (Where Clause)xyz"
"xyzCondition (Where Clause)xyz" → "xyzCondition (Where Clause)xyz"
"In Condition (Where Clause) Between" → "In  Between"
"In Condition (Where Clause) Between" → "InBetween"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the below should suffice

```
str.replaceAll("(\\s|^)Condition \\(Where Clause\\)(\\s|$)","")
```